# ¿Hay alguna palabra que describa cuando dos o mas personas dicen o hacen algo al mismo tiempo?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos, español-neutral

Realmente no hago uso de este tipo de páginas o palabras, pero estoy escribiendo algo y necesito informarme, me gustaría una respuesta concisa.

Comment: Si esta es la primera vez que usas esta página (stack) en particular, te recomiendo visitar [help] y [tour] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de la misma. A esta pregunta le falta un poco de contexto y si has mirado ya algún término. Mírate los enlaces para aprender a redactar preguntas que den suficiente información al resto de la comunidad para que estos entiendan qué necesitar entender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo usaría "decir / hacer algo "[al unísono](https://www.lexico.com/es/definicion/al_unisono)":

> 1 De manera uniforme y conjunta, sin discrepancias.
>
> trabajar **al unísono**; todo el pueblo **al unísono** apoyó la decisión de su gobernador
>
> 2 Al mismo tiempo.
>
> En el transcurso de la ceremonia, padres y padrinos responden, **al unísono**, al sacerdote oficiante

Comment: Gracias! era la respuesta que estaba esperando

Comment: At least in English, just being at the same time is denoted by "simultaneous", while "in unison" denotes, well, unity.  Do the Spanish cognates have the same meaning?

Comment: Well, I think "al unísono" conveys the idea OP wants to express better than "en simultáneo" (simultaneously). Unlike the former, the latter may be used for the same person doing two or more things at the same time. "al unísono" clearly reflects a plurality of individuals.

Answer (score 3):

Sin explicar si el hecho de que esas personas hagan o digan algo al mismo tiempo es intencional o no, yo voy a proponer el término **sincronía**, que creo que es el que mejor se ajusta a la descripción dada.

> [sincronía](https://dle.rae.es/sincron%C3%ADa?m=form)

> 1. f. Coincidencia de hechos o fenómenos en el tiempo.

Y muy parecido a sincronizar tienes **acompasar** (aunque no necesariamente *compasar*).

> [acompasar](https://dle.rae.es/acompasar?m=form)

> 1. tr. Hacer que una cosa o acción se corresponda con otra u otras.